# Trying to get onYouTubePlayerReady to fire

Tags: youtube-api

I'm taking my first step with learning the [YouTube api](https://developers.google.com/youtube/js_api_reference).

Here's my html:

```
<iframe width="640" height="360" src="//www.youtube.com/v/FLMpFXUZOs4?version=3&enablejsapi=1&rel=0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

And here's my JavaScript:

```
function onYouTubePlayerReady() {
    alert('yay!')
}
```

onYouTubePlayerReady is not firing.

I tried to save it in jsFiddle, but I don't see a Save button.
I only see a "Run", "Debug on mobile", "Tidyup", "JSHint" and "Collaboration" button.

Comment: Is it [onYouTubeIframeAPIReady](https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference)?

Comment: try with this live example : http://jsbin.com/cocatuta/1/edit?html,js,output , can help :)